# PHPMailer can't find SMTP class

Tags: phpmailer, contact-form-7

i've installed PHPMailer over composer on hostinger.com (webhost). The original version of PHPMailer was 5.0 so I upgraded to 6.6 after i came across this error when submitting a ContactForm7 WordPress plugin form.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP' not found in /home/uxxxxxxxx/domains/rebelcitytour.com/public_html/staging25/wp-includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php:1953
```

I've upgraded to version 6.6 of PHPMailer, I've checked the PHPMailer folder. It exists. And has three files in it...

```
Exception.php  PHPMailer.php  SMTP.php
```

Yet, the plugin PHP code can't seem to find SMTP class? Weird right?

I've included this code in load.php of my plugin root director...

```
require_once '/staging25/wp-includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
```

[Link to bug on system](https://staging25.rebelcitytour.com/booking-form/#wpcf7-f345-p346-o1)

Comment: It sounds like a namespace problem related to you using a separate version of PHPMailer, when Wordpress includes one already, so there's no need to do that. [The docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-PHPMailer-in-WordPress) tell you how to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like suggested above. It was a namespace issue caused by a dev declaring a global variable in local scope.